# How to set up a Password-Protected Website to test HTTP authentication challenge?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, http, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to test if my authentication code is working by testing it against a password protected website. How can I use the built in Apache server on the mac to create a test website so that I can test the `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` delegate method?
Are there any blogs/resources that show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the simple HTTP authentication? 
You can setup an Apache and create a .htaccess file in the protected directory with content

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
require valid-user
```

The file .htpasswd needs to have user and password info in syntax user:crypt(password) using the output generated by crypt.

Comment: Can you provide a link to any resource that would guide me how to do this in detail?